# How to get data type of each column in table of dynamodb using java api

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

Hi I am trying to create a UI tool for QA team where QA team can view dynamodb records. I have given a filter in my UI. Now the problem is, I should be knowing all column data types before setting key value in scan filter expression.

I knew there is a function "describe" which should give all this info. but this function does not give data type of all column.

Comment: Has the non-key attributes in the item are fixed? Because typically all items may not have the same number of non-key attributes.

Comment: ya non-key attributes in the item are fixed.

Comment: If the attributes are fixed and know the data type during design time, you can set the data types as hidden variables in UI and pass it to back end for each selected attributes. This way you should be able to form the FilterExpression accordingly. Other option is to have this mapping in back end as key value pairs (attribute name as key and data type as values).

Comment: ya mapping can be done but this will be little costlier as I have to create pojo and add annotation then every time I will get data in java object again converting it JSON to send back to UI ... lot of work .. 
But the other idea where we save the data type on UI side sound good to me ... let me give it a try ...  thanks man